# Executing code on storyboard finish in Blend 4

Tags: user-interface, expression-blend

In my Blend application I'm making the program fade out when the user closes it. I can get the fading storyboard to play, but I don't know how to check when it's done so I can execute code to actually close the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the StoryBoard [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979733%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Event